# How to convert a slice to alias slice in go?

Tags: go, type-conversion, slice, user-defined-types

I defined my `Int` type as `int`.

I want to convert a slice of `Int` to a slice of `int`, but got a compile error:

> cannot convert c (type []Int) to type []int

How can I fix this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Int int

func main() {
    var c = []Int{}
    var x = []int( c )
    fmt.Println(len(x))
}
```

Comment: What you do is not aliasing. You do not need aliasing. Forget that term. Take the Tour of Go which explains how to convert types with identical underlying types.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `Int` type is not an alias of `int`, it's a new type with `int` being its underlying type. This type of conversion is not supported / allowed by the language spec. More specifically, converting a slice type to another where the element type is different is not allowed.

### The safe way

If you only need an `[]int` "view" of the `[]Int`, the safe way to "convert" would be to create a copy of the `[]Int` slice but with a type of `[]int`, and use a `for range` loop and convert each individual element from `Int` to `int` type:

```
var c = []Int{1, 2}

x := make([]int, len(c))
for i, v := range c {
    x[i] = int(v)
}
fmt.Println(x)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZSQURHGxkV3)):

```
[1 2]
```

### The unsafe way

There is also an "unsafe" way:

```
var c = []Int{1, 2}

var x []int = *(*[]int)(unsafe.Pointer(&c))
fmt.Println(x)
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Y4C01Z6w2yI).

What happens here is that the address of `c` (which is `&c`) is converted to [`unsafe.Pointer`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer) (all pointers can be converted to this), which then is converted to `*[]int` (`unsafe.Pointer` can be converted to any pointer type), and then this pointer is dereferenced which gives a value of type `[]int`. In this case it is safe because the memory layout of `[]Int` and `[]int` is identical (because `Int` has `int` as its underlying type), but in general, use of package [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) should be avoided whenever possible.

### If `Int` would be a "true" alias

Note that if `Int` would be a "true" alias to `int`, the conversion would not even be needed:

```
var c = []Int{1, 2}

var x []int = c
fmt.Println(x)
```

Output is the same as above (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aXcVzKVxbfd)). The reason why this works is because writing `[]Int` is identical to writing `[]int`, they are the same type, so you don't even need a conversion here.

### By using a slice type

Also note that if you would create a new type with `[]int` as its underlying type, you could use type conversion:

```
type IntSlice = []int

func main() {
    var c = IntSlice{1, 2}

    var x []int = []int(c)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Output is again the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Zz8b5uUcT9x).

Comment: Downvoter care to comment?

Comment: This answer seems fine to me. Yes, downvoter should put down his views, am upvoting it to make up :) 

p.s.: I note that you later added a part to your answer which incidentally I also illustrated

Comment: There is nothing unsafe about the "unsafe" solution.

Comment: @segfault There's nothing "unsafe" with the **current** version. The Go backward compatibility guarantee does not guarantee apps using package `unsafe` will continue to work with future versions and on all platforms. It's unlikely that this unsafe solution will break in a future version, but there's no guarantee. There is guarantee that the safe way will continue to work on all platforms in future releases too.

Comment: If past design decisions are any indication, I would not put it past them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not creating `Int` as an alias, doing

`type Int int`

Will create `Int` as a *new* type that can't interoperate with `int`.

The proper way to create `Int` as an alias is

`type Int = int`

With this change your program is ok.

Comment: I don’t know why the downvote, the @johlo's answer really show how to create an alias in Go (Go 1.9 and higher). Nobody else mention the existence of real alias in Go. See here: https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#language

Answer (score 0):

Technically, `type Int int` does not define an [alias](https://golang.org/ref/spec#AliasDecl), but a completely new type. Even though `Int` and `int` now have identical [underlying types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) and can be converted to each other, that does not apply to slices. More about allowed conversions is in the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a slice a simply points to an underlying array of the designated type (in this case the types are different, `Int` and `int`). So unless your underlying type is the same a conversion won't work. Just to illustrate this something like this would work though:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Int int
type IntSl []int

func main() {
    var c = IntSl{2, 3, 4}
    var x []int
    x = []int(c)
    var a Int
    var b int
    a = 1
    b = int(a)
    fmt.Println(len(x), a, b, c)
}
```

Playground : https://play.golang.org/p/ROOX1XoXg1j

As @icza points out there's the `unsafe` way & of course you can always do the conversion looping over each of the elements which could be expensive.